# Is an abstract method in c++ ever called?

Tags: c++, function, class, abstract

Let's say I have an abstract class with a function called `print`. And let's say I have another class that inherits from the elder class and defines the function `print`.
Is it right to say that the elder classes function `print` will never be called?
My debate is in a case where I have an elder pointer to a child. And I call the `print` function using this pointer. Unless I declared the function to be `virtual` it should try to use the abstract function. But it can't, and here is where I get stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I added an example. Thanks for this suggestion since it solved my question. There's no such thing as a non virtual abstract method.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
 void print()=0;//I have to add virtual before declaring function
};
void A::print(){
    cout<<"1"<<endl;
    }

class B: public A{
    public:
    void print(){cout<<"2"<<endl;}
    };

int main(){
  B b;
  b.print();
  A* a=&b;
  a->print();
  b.A::print();//here I called the abstract method
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try that on code?

Comment: You can always call it explicitly, e.g. `p->Base::foo();`

Comment: Hang on. If you don't have `virtual` functions, you can't have an abstract class on your hands. At least not in the C++ runtime polymorphism sense of word "abstract". Can you clarify? Preferably with actual code.

Comment: Reading documentation often helps: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual

Comment: Your question will be more clear if you actually use some code for demonstration.

Comment: Ptaq666 As you suggested I added an example which solved my question.
StoryTeller You are right it has to be virtual. Thanks everyone.

Comment: `void print()=0;` is an error. Only virtual functions can have `= 0;`

Answer (score 0):

> Let's say I have an abstract class with a function called "print". And let's say I have another class that inherits from the father class and defines the function print. Is it right to say that the "father" classes function print will never be called?

No.

> My debate is in a case where I have a "father" pointer to a "son". And I call the print function using this pointer. Unless I declared the function to be virtual it should try to use the abstract function.

Right, so if it isn't `virtual`, the "father" function will be called (or, at least, an attempt will be made to do so). This answers your previous question.

If it is `virtual`, overriding means the child function will be called. However, it is still possible to call the base version (for example, from within the child version) like `Father::print()`, if a definition is provided for that function.

> But it can't, and here is where I get stuck.

I don't know what you mean by this.